# golang wait for io.Writer to be written to

Tags: go, io, buffer

The [`http.Server`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server) type in the golang standard [`net/http`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) package has a field named `ErrorLog`,  which is of type `log.Logger`.

This is how `ErrorLog` is set up in my `http.Server`:

```
// set up HTTP server
server = &http.Server{
    Addr:      getPortFromConfig(),
    Handler:   handler,
    ErrorLog:  log.New(io.MultiWriter(stdout, fileout), "", 1),
}
```

So here, the `io.MultiWriter()` function creates a new `io.Writer` that will copy all writes from my `http.Server` into a file as well as stdout. It works like a charm.

**However**, I would like to intercept the data and format it before it is written to the file.

How is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own writer which implements "Write([]byte) error".
When you create this writer, you give him the file writer as arguments. 
Each time your writer receive something, it formats it and then calls the "Write" method on the file writer.
Something like :

```
type MyFormatter struct {
       fileWriter io.Writer
 }

 func (m *MyFormatter) Write(buf []byte) error {
       formattedBytes := FormatBytes(buf)
       m.fileWriter.Write(formattedBytes)
 }
```

Haven't tested that code, it is only pseudo code!

EDIT: You can even use embedded writer

```
type MyFormatter struct {
       io.Writer
 }

 func (m *MyFormatter) Write(buf []byte) error {
       formattedBytes := FormatBytes(buf)
       m.Writer.Write(formattedBytes)
 }
```